# Ocean-themed fantasy trilogy: girl goes through a portal in her father's workshop, searches for her mermaid(?) mother there

Tags: magical-creatures, childrens-novel, story-identification

The only things I remember about this book was it was about a brother and a sister (although I want to say more about the sister) and they were at a fair or carnival with their dad who raised them because the mom was MIA or whatever. I think the dad had a mirror portal thing in his workshop or at home and it could teleport to where the mom was.

But she was like, a sea creature or mermaid or something? The daughter went through it and the other sea creature people spoke a different language but they told her about her mom or something. They seemed hostile.

Anyway, at the end some sea creature attacked the land that the kids lived on but lost I guess.

I remember this being one book from a trilogy. I cannot for the life of me find it, no matter how many words I Google.